# Traveling to Prague with a Hungary Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, international-travel, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, visa-shopping

I am an Indian student in Dublin, Ireland. I have planned a 10-day trip to Prague but was unable to secure an appointment with the Czech Republic Agency. Therefore, I decided to include a few days in Budapest, Hungary, in my itinerary, as I was able to get an appointment for a Hungarian Schengen Visa. Is this an acceptable plan? Additionally, my arrival and departure will be in and from Prague, so I will travel by bus from Prague to Budapest and back.

Comment: How few days exactly?

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is called visa-shopping, and it's frowned upon by the Schengen countries.

The rules say that you should apply to the country that is the main purpose of your visit, or where you'll spend most time. For your original plan, the Czech Republic is the place to apply.

If the immigration officers suspect what's really gone on they can make life difficult for any future visa application.

It's not clear from your question, but you seem to indicate that you have already started (and possibly completed) the process with Hungary, and arranged your flights.

Changing your itinerary to spend most time in Budapest might be a solution, but it's a six hour drive (longer by bus) from Prague to Budapest, passing through Austria or Slovakia on the way. It's going to be difficult to explain, then, why you flew to Prague for a holiday in Budapest.

Changing your flights and going to Prague another time might be a better option.

Comment: I agree that visa shopping isn't looked upon very favorably. Since most of your trip is meant to be in Prague, it may raise eyebrows. At this point, since the Hungarian visa process is underway, I'd reconsider adjusting your plans to focus more on Budapest instead of Prague for this trip, to better align with the visa application. Prague will still be there for another visit when it's easier to get the proper visa. Just my two cents to avoid any issues - better safe than sorry with border control!

Comment: @SarahWilson I would hope that four years after OP's original question, the visa process has already concluded some time ago. Then we also had a whole pandemic which could have messed up OP's travel plans. :-)